# How to get 50 points so I can comment on something that I think is useful information

Tags: discussion

1.The problem is I need 50 points to be able to leave a comment on something and I feel the information is relevant.

2.I have went as far as making a name then attempting to comment only to find a very understandable prove you're not an idiot or troll or waste of time or insert whatever preference you have.

3.I have tried what I'm currently doing right now.

4.Bonus, yea I read all 3.  [Powering an LED from USB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/644123/powering-an-led-from-usb/644124#644124?newreg=7b7982d8da664a9b8b4247801d087366) This question is how I found myself here.

Comment: Matthew Warren - Hi, (a) You posted this on the main site, but it isn't an on-topic technical question, so that isn't allowed. Instead, since you're asking about *using* the site, that has to be done on our Meta site, so it's been migrated to here. (b) You need 5 points to use Meta and AFAIK those points have to be gained on the main site (i.e. getting upvoted here won't help). In short - you have to add some value to the site, to use Meta too. (c) Until you have some points, I'll post an answer (albeit a link-only answer) to explain what you can do.

Comment: Matthew, if your are reasonably skilled in electronics and the use of language, you can turn anything like a comment into a valid answer. For instance, you may want to ask the guy raising the question for clarification but, if you have the time and skills you can offer an answer that covers all the bases. Having said that, the question is 18 months or so old so, I suspect that your contribution may not be that important in the wider sense of this site. Maybe you can reveal why you think your desired contribution isn't convertible to a bona fide answer.

Comment: @Andyaka - Hi, Re: "*Maybe you can reveal why you think your desired contribution isn't convertible to a bona fide answer.*" FYI please note my earlier comment. Currently the OP doesn't have the points required to reply to you. Re: "*you can turn anything like a comment into a valid answer.*" That's not true, even with the best knowledge & language skills e.g. (constructive) criticism of an answer or adding a relevant link *must* be done in a comment, not in an answer. Since we don't know what the OP wants to write in a comment, let's try to set correct expectations around use of answers :)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the site. I'm sorry that you found your wish to be useful frustrated. It's good to have new members who join in order to assist others. Hopefully the initial bad experience will not stop you 'hanging in there' and getting involved. There is a vast amount of technical capability here, and we are always very happy to have more added.

I feel that the 50 point requirement for commenting is not a marvelous idea. I think that the aim is to avoid "drive by commenting" by people who are not engaged with the site and who may spam or post low quality comments. Once people have engaged enough to get 50 points they are presumably deemed to be real enough that their comments are liable to be of value.

One method is to post an answer which is more of a comment but tries hard to address the question. Ideally it will be good enough to be regarded as an answer and you will get upvotes. However, if it is really only comment quality a moderator may choose to convert it to a comment and your aim is achieved.

The danger of doing this is that you may get downvotes with no existing reputation. If you do that 2 or 3 times the system will lock you out from further Q&A until you improve your existing answers. This is automatic and we have no control over it. If this happens I try to assist the user to improve the questions or answers, but it can be hard.

If you do post answers and they get downvoted you can use the flag 'button' to request moderator attention and we can see how we can help.

I suggest that you try posting answers that are as "answer like" as possible. It should not take long to start to gain enough 'rep' to comment.

**_________________**

A point worth noting - downvotes on meta (ie here) do not count as general downvotes and have a different meaning to downvotes on the main site. Here it is more an agree/disagree mechanism. I'm not sure why you have the downvotes here that you have BUT they are not significant site-wide.

Answer (score 2):

The restriction of requiring 50 points before you can comment is mentioned in the [Help Center](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/help), at the top of the Comment Everywhere privilege page [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

The article below linked from the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) explains more reasoning & background, as well as what to do to gain those points:

[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

It's not a perfect system, but it's the one we have and we have to fit within it.

Comment: And also [Why do we need 50 reputation to make comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/why-do-we-need-50-reputation-to-make-comments) .